# Python Efficiently Remove Specific Entries from Messy List of Lists

Tags: python, list

Does someone know how to efficiently remove entries from a messy list of lists of tuples?
I am dealing with a list containing lists of a warring amount of tuples and I want to remove all the tuples from the list of lists that are in another list of tuples.

It would be awesome if the solution works for the general case of this type of problem and is also efficient in runtime.

My list looks like this:

```
list = [[(1, 5), (1, 7), (1, 8)], [(3, 3)], [(4, 2), (4, 3)], [(6, 6)]]
```

I want to remove the items in another list of tuples from my list:

```
list_delete = [(1, 7), (3, 3), (4, 2)]
```

I want the result to look like:

```
result = [[(1, 5), (1, 8)], [], [(4, 3)], [(6, 6)]]
```

Comment: Also, avoid to name your list "list" as this is a python keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can efficiently remove entries from your list of lists of tuples by using list comprehensions. Here's a Python solution that works for the general case of this problem:

```py
# Your input list
main_list = [[(1, 5), (1, 7), (1, 8)], [(3, 3)], [(4, 2), (4, 3)], [(6, 6)]]

# List of tuples to be removed
list_delete = [(1, 7), (3, 3), (4, 2)]

# Create a set for faster lookup
delete_set = set(list_delete)

# Use list comprehensions to filter out tuples
result = [[item for item in sublist if item not in delete_set] for sublist in main_list]

print(result)
```

The key to efficiency here is using a set (delete_set) to store the tuples to be removed. Sets offer constant-time average lookup, making the removal process much faster than iterating through the list_delete for each element in your list of lists. The list comprehensions efficiently filter out the unwanted tuples from each sublist.